# Tableau If Statement

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api

Here is [Tableau DataViz (tab "Other Regions")](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/logarithmic_order_quantity/Other_Regions)

I am trying to create columns that

(1) explicitly list region

(2) remaining regions come under "Other Regions"

Value for "Other_Region"

`If NOT Region="Ontario"
or Region="Prarie" 
or Region="Quebec"
or Region="Yukon"
Then "Other Regions"
Else Region end`

Output is not what I expected. It only lists

(1) Ontario

(2) Other Regions

I was also expecting

- Prarie
- Quebec
- Yukon

My actual data has 200+ regions, hence the need for streamlined statement.

Please guide.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more logical to me /

```
If NOT Region="Ontario"
AND NOT Region="Prarie" 
AND NOT Region="Quebec"
AND NOT Region="Yukon"
Then "Other Regions"
Else Region end
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two alternatives using positive logic, which is often more clear.

```
case Region
  when "Ontario" then Region
  when "Prairie" then Region
  when "Quebec" then Region
  when "Ontario" then Region
  else "Other Regions"
end
```

**Or** even easier to maintain, first **create a set** based on the Region field. Name it Interesting_Regions, and select the regions you wish to be treated specially as members of the set.

Then you can either use that set on shelves to control Tableau, and/or implement the calculated field as:

```
if [Interesting_Regions] then Region else "Other Regions" end
```

Answer (score 2):

NOT only applies to the first condition. you have to wrap in () to apply NOT to all, like this:

```
If NOT (Region="Ontario"
or Region="Prarie" 
or Region="Quebec"
or Region="Yukon")
Then "Other Regions"
Else Region end
```